# Does a lump of baryonic matter have a well-defined particle number?

Tags: particle-physics, condensed-matter, identical-particles, matter

From reading about quantized electromagnetism, it seems that many forms of light (e.g. lasers) don't have well-defined numbers of photons, or in other words are superpositions of different number states.

Is this the case for baryonic matter?

For example, say I have a lump of pure iron of about 1kg which has zero net charge. My thought is that the lump of iron can have the same total mass/energy while having different numbers of atoms. To illustrate:

1. Adding mass-energy in the form of atoms, we raise the total energy by $\Delta E=m_{Fe}c^2=8.33146051\times10^{-9}J$ per atom.
2. We can raise the total energy by the same amount by adding an equivalent amount of heat (increasing the temperature by $1.8514357\times10^{-11}K$).

So can the lump of iron be in a superposition of (more atoms, less heat) and (fewer atoms, more heat)? Does it always exist as a well-defined number (of atoms), even if I don't count the number of atoms precisely?

Why/why not?

Comment: you can determine the number of iron ions exactly, even if will be very large for 1kg of iron. something like a superposition of number states does not exist. The number of photons a laser emits per second is also well defined and not a superposition of number states.

Comment: @trula I've edited the question to be more specific. If I'm not mistaken, quantum fields can in fact be in a superposition of number states: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fock_state

Comment: You asked for 1kg of iron, the mass,  not the volume, which will increase with temperature, also you did not ask for the energy, so I can't see any "superposition"

Comment: @trula The answer isn't clear. If my question is stupid, could you please explain why clearly? While the answer to this may immediately be very clear to you, it certainly isn't to me, so I'd appreciate a constructive answer. Please also address my comment about superpositions of number states. Please see this for reference https://link.springer.com/article/10.1134/S0030400X11110075

Comment: If you divide the mass of your iron bei the mass of one iron atom you get the number as precise, as one knows the mass of one atom.So if the mass of one atom is not known to a high decimal, there is an error marge for the number, but this has nothing to do with superposition. In light you have in some instances superposition not of numbers, but of states of the atoms emitting the photons, or you have to give me a reference, where you read of superposition of numbers in a laser..

Comment: Maybe rephrase the question, with an isotropically pure metal….like Aluminium.  And a better mass, say 12 g of carbon 12….. makes for few caveats and a clearer answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the answer you were looking for, but there's an important different between photons and baryonic matter. The number of photons in a process doesn't need to be conserved. You can shoot an electron to freely roam space, and the Feynman diagram of the electron shooting a photon is allowed, and it can happen many times. Therefore, quantum superpositions of the EM field with different photon numbers are allowed and make sense physically.

Baryonic matter (and electrons too), on the other hand, have to be conserved in number. If you create an electron you need to create a positron as well.

Also, notice that there exist superselection rules in quantum mechanics. A superselection rules occurs when there's two sectors on the Hilbert space, with states $|\phi\rangle$ and $|\psi\rangle$ such that $\langle\phi|O|\psi\rangle=0$ for all operators $O$. Then, superpositions of states in those two sectors of the Hilbert space is forbidden. In this context, forbidden just means that a quantum superposition is indistinguishable from a statistical one. In other words, there can't be quantum coherence between those two sectors because they can't talk to each other. Electric charge is one of those things that determines superselection sectors on the Hilbert space. So your proposal about having superpositions of different numbers of electrons is forbidden to begin with. You could get away with having superpositions of different numbers of atoms, which are neutrally charged, but then you would be violating some leptonic number or baryon number superselection rule.

Also, from a different point of view, we know from decoherence that macroscopic states of matter can't be in a quantum superposition, so this is also another reason why your proposed lump of iron can't really be in a quantum superposition of different states, regardless of which type of state.

Comment: Thanks very much, this makes a lot of sense!

Comment: @p-c-spaniel Just an afterthought, I've read that there may be processes which violate baryon number: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electroweak_star. Could this (theoretically) allow superselection rules to be violated in extreme circumstances?